# Django image saving issue

Tags: python, django

**VIEWS.PY**

```
def Profile(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    profile = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
    if profile.is_valid():
        profile.save()
    return redirect("Profile")
profile = UserForm(instance=request.user)
return render(request, "book/Profile.html", context={"user": request.user, "profile": profile})
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
username = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label='Username', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}))
email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}))
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False, label='First name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}))
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False, label='Last name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}))
avatar = forms.ImageField(required=False, widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}))

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'avatar')
```

**MODELS.PY**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='UserAvatar/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
   if created:
      Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
   instance.profile.save()
```

**PROFILE.HTML**

```
         <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ profile }}

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

**SETTINGS.PY**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Well, I'm kind of having an issue here. I'm new in Django and I've recently uploaded an image from forms.Form but now I'm using forms.ModelForm and don't really know what the problem is. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you setup `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in settings.py ?

Comment: Could you please explain what is the problem? Do you have an error? Does file missing when you try to save/load it?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych No, there's no error whatsoever, I also get an image thru request.FILES , but it just doesn't save. All other information is saving fine.

Comment: @NirjalPaudel Yes, I did